# Windows Server 2012 cannot access web sites

Tags: networking, printer, tcp, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012 that has gone a little crazy in the last 24 hours. It can't access any websites, internal to the network or on the web. I can ping google.ca for example and it resolves fine and I get back replies. What is weird is I can't even get to our Printer Web GUI, or Firewall web interface (via IP addresses). None of it works. I can ping them, they are working fine, and I can access them from any other workstation.

It's isolated to this Server but I can't pin it down.

This all started when users printing to an AD printer suddenly couldn't print. The jobs were queuing in the AD's queue but not going to the printer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what happens if you tracert to a website?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we managed to get it solved. After I posted everything started going down all across the network. Users lost access to NAS, Internet and everything else connected to the network. Though maybe the switch so we subbed in a known working one, no change. Pings to other network nodes came back with a 'General Failure" message so I ran a netsh to clear the IP stack and that ran through no problem. Upon reboot, though the interface had a autoconfig IP. When I looked at the adapter it showed the proper DNS settings, but the IP, mask and gateway were blank, even though the "Use the following.." was selected. Toggled to DHCP and back and reentered the IP info, and everything came back up. 
I think the NIC might be flaking out on us. I guess we should install that backup controller that's sitting in the box in the server room, now. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to reboot the server?
I had the same problem on my Laptop (Win7), i can ping all IP addresses, but can't open any web session!

I believe, its a problem in the firewall (Symantec firewall)
If you don't have a third party firewall, then it could be one of Windows services, but the question is which one!